# Unable to find created database row

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a function that creates a keyword and updates an attribute with a user's id if the keyword does not already exist. If the keyword already exists it updates attribute with user's id in an array.

I have an issue of keyword duplication when a request contains multiple updates for one keyword, when the keyword does not pre-exist the request.

I have tried adding a sequalize.transaction, and have also attempted to add a setTimeout.

```
const findOrCreateKeyword = async function(keyword, keywordModel){
  // await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 10000));
   return keywordModel.sequelize.transaction( async t => {
    return keywordModel.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            keyword: keyword
        },
     transaction: t
    }).catch(err => console.log('Error: findKeyword: ', err))
    })
}
```

```
 var [keywordObj, created] = await findKeyword(keyword, KeywordModel)
```

If a keyword does not pre-exist the request, and the request contains several 'updates' to a keyword, I expect the first 'update' to create the keyword in the table (variable created should be true), and the other 'updates' to add users id to the userID array attribute (created should be false for subsequent updates).

What actually occurs is that the updates created duplicate keywords (created is true each time).